# PHP: trying to merge array, but not an actual array when array returns from a function?

Tags: php, arrays, class, function, merge

I have a function, and it returns an array.

```
class myarray
{
 public function getAr()
   {
      // mysql query
      while($dd= $database->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
           {
               $data[] = $dd; //there's values in the array
           }
               return $data;
   }
 public function get3()
   {
      // mysl query
      while($dd= $database->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
           {
               $data[] = $dd; //there's values in the array
           }
               return $data;
   }
```

}

How come I tried to merge together the array:

```
$get = new myarray();
$arrayAr = $get->getAr();
$array3 = $get->get3();
$new_array = array_merge($arrayAr ,$array3);
```

It says that its not an array?

```
array_merge() [function.array-merge]: Argument #1 is not an array
```

But I can `print_r($arrayAr);` and its like an array?

Help?

Thanks

Comment: I don't think you'd really name your class `array` - that could cause some confusion... Is this the code you are using or some pseudo code to simplify the problem?

Comment: `$d` gets out of nowhere too.

Comment: I'm not even sure how you could run this the `class array` should give you a `PHP Parse error`. But besides that your code returns an array containing NULL two times. Which is to be expected since `$d`, like @Shikiryu stated, comes out of nothing.

Answer (score 1):

`array` is the name of a builtin; you must change the name of your class. Additionally, you should define `$d` ([live demo](http://ideone.com/LSjUu)):

```
<?php
class MyArray {
  public function getAr() {
    $d = 42;
    $data = array($d);
    return $data;
  }
  public function get3() {
    $d = 43;
    $data = array($d);
    return $data;
  }
}
$get = new MyArray();
$arrayAr = $get->getAr();
$array3 = $get->get3();
var_export(array_merge($arrayAr ,$array3)); // [0 => 42, 1 => 43]
```

---

In response to the edited version: What if the query doesn't return anything? And note you `$database` is undefined. Moreover, *it is not actually a database*, but a `PDOStatement` object. Assuming that it is in fact a valid PDO object, you should simply use [`fetchAll`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php):

```
class MyArray {
  protected $statement;
  public function query($pdo, $sql) {
    $this->statement = $pdo->query($sql);
  }

  // Don't forget to call query before this method.
  public function getAr() {
    return $this->statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
  }
}
```

Comment: I need to have `$data[]` instead of array($d); there's supposed to have populated values in there, I just left it blank for simplicity

Comment: @andrewliu Well, I can't regard code or requirements you haven't included in the question. But sure, if you define `$data` right after `$d`, you can use `$data[] = $d;`.

Comment: I edited my OP, I wonder if it makes sense what my problem is now?

Comment: @andrewliu In the future, please don't make drastic edits to your question. That will leave all future visitors confused. Instead, simply ask a new question (and maybe link to it in the comments or so). Your problem is unrelated to `array_merge`. Instead, your query either returns an empty result or `$database` is not, well, a database (calling `fetch` strongly suggests so). I have amended this answer.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the problem is that you are using a saved name for your class.  You really shouldn't use keywords with other meanings in the language as variable names.   Just like you wouldn't call a variable `array_merge` because there is already a function called that...

This code seems to work for me -

```
class customArray{
  public function getAr(){
    $data[] = 'Stack';
    return $data;
  }

  public function get3(){
    $data[] = 'Overflow';
    return $data;
  } 
}

$get = new customArray();
$arrayAr = $get->getAr();
$array3 = $get->get3();
print_r(array_merge($arrayAr ,$array3))
```

Outputs -

```
Array
(
    [0] => Stack
    [1] => Overflow
)
```

However if I use the class name `array`, I'll get this error -

> PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_ARRAY, expecting T_STRING...